# Where can I download spidermonkey 1.8.5 precompiled static library for iOS?

Tags: iphone, spidermonkey, .a

Meeting the requirements to `configure` and then spend hours trying to fix issues while `make` I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I think this might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation/Rebranding_SpiderMonkey_(1.8.5)

Comment: thank you, but that's where I came from.